# Php Dom Document

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I have an html content like below:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 additional-nav">
 <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
   <li><a href="account.html">My Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="wishlist.html">My Wishlist</a></li>
   <li><a href="checkout.html">Checkout</a></li>
   <li><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
   <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This HTMl content will be dynamic. Means parent element can be div , span , anchor or any other html tag.

I want to get the first element type using php DOM.

Like in the current html , parent element type is **div**.

How I can get it.

Comment: How do you want by php or javascript ?, did you try anything if yes share with us ?

Comment: I want to get it using PHP DomDocument.

Comment: I have already tried documentElement. Its giving blank.

Comment: Got the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got two solutions of it.

```
        $block_str = '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 additional-nav">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
                           <li><a href="account.html">My Account</a></li> 
                           <li><a href="wishlist.html">My Wishlist</a></li> 
                           <li><a href="checkout.html">Checkout</a></li> 
                           <li><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li> 
                           <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
                       </ul>
                     </div>';
        $document = new DOMDocument;
        $document->loadHTML($block_str);
        $body_obj = $document->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
        $first_node_name = $body_obj->item(0)->nodeName;
```

We can get it by following document functions as well.

```
    $first_node_name = $document->documentElement->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeName;
```

So in **$first_node_name**, I got the first element.